# Blocking/Disabling App-V Package on Certain Workstations

Tags: app-v

I have an App-V package that I want to disable on a small number of computers. The reason is we are doing a comparison test between App-V and traditional installs. So the package still needs to be available on all other workstations, to all users, and other App-V packages still need to work on these pilot machines.

Therefore we need to disable a single app/package per workstation.

My question is this: would the following command achieve this?

```
SFTMIME DELETE APP:appname
```

Or would the package re-appear when a user logs on? If this is not the way to do it, is there another way? App-V version is 4.5.

**UPDATE:** I discovered that the above does not work. Instead you need to delete the package rather than the app, and do it using the package GUID rather than the name.

I have also discovered that the package does in fact reappear when the user next logs on. So, I have put the SFTMIME command in a .bat script and made it run as a logon script via Group Policy. It just remains to be seen whether this runs before or after the App-V client updates from the server, and whether it is consistent.

Comment: Matt - If you answer your own question, it's helpful to put the answer as an actual answer instead of inside the body of the question. Want to move that info to the answer and collect the points for it? :-)

Comment: Thanks - although unfortunately this does not work so the question remains unanswered.